# Handle Ajax sucess and error in jsp

Tags: java, ajax, jsp

I have Form in JSP which have two input boxes along with submit and clear button like this

```
<form name="loginForm" method="GET" action="Ajaxexample" id="loginForm">
 <table>
 <tr>
 <td>From Date</td><td><input type="text" name="n1" value=""/></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>End Date</td><td><input type="text" name="n2" value=""/></td>
 </tr>
 <tr></tr>
 <tr>
 <td><input type="submit" name="validpro_insert" value="Insert"></td>
 <td><input type="reset" name="validpro_clear" value="Clear"></td>
 </tr>                     
 </table>
 </form>
```

As I have called the servlet using get method in form tag which is used to get data from database via JDBC API and to handle the response I have use ajax  like this

```
  protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {    

         processRequest(request, response);
         System.out.println("In get");
          PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
          String responseStr = "";
          responseStr = addUser(request); // Return either error/success
          System.out.println("Reponse:" + responseStr);  
           response.setContentType("application/json"); 
           response.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8"); 
           response.getWriter().write(responseStr);
           out.print(responseStr);
```

As I have to write some code to get data from DB in servlet and return that response to ajax which handle success and error on the same jsp like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jq.js"></script>   
   <script type="text/javascript">

        var form = $('#loginForm');
        form.submit(function () {
        $.ajax({
        type: form.attr('method'),
        url: form.attr('action'),
        data: form.serialize(),

          error: function (theRequest,textStatus, errorThrown) {
                     // Success = false;
                      alert (theRequest.responseText);
                      alert(errorThrown);
                   alert('No graph found');//doesnt goes here
            },
        success: function (data) {

                var result=data;
                alert(result);
        }     
                });
                return false;
            });
        </script>
```

But the problem is that I am not getting any value from servlet in ajax to handle success or error

I think I am facing this problem due to servlet doget() method code.. if there is any other problem plz let me know. Any help should be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with these changes in my code, it runs successfully

```
 protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                throws ServletException, IOException {
            response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
            try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) 

                 String responseSend = "";

            String from = request.getParameter("n1");
            String to = request.getParameter("n2");    

              if ((from == null) || (from.equals(""))) {

                System.out.println("From null");
                responseSend = "error";

            } 
              else if ((to == null) || (to.equals(""))) {

                System.out.println("End null");
               responseSend  = "error";

            }
              else{            
                      //jdbc code              
            System.out.println("got it");
            int n1 = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("n1"));
            int n2 = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("n2"));
            responseSend = "code";           
              }

             out.print(responseSend);

        }          
            }

        @Override
        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                throws ServletException, IOException {
           System.out.println("In get");
            processRequest(request, response);
    }
```

As I have added a new method processrequest() with request and response parameters which will return the text/HTML to our Ajax code on the same jsp.Firstly I am confused with success/error in ajax code but now I have found that

```
 error: function (theRequest,textStatus, errorThrown) {
                          alert (theRequest.responseText);
                          alert(errorThrown);
                },

  success: function (data) {

                var result=data;
                alert(result);
        }
```

The error will be called when it doesn't found servlet at given URL and success will be called when it successfully call the servlet with given type and servlet URL.

Answer (score 0):

I have pasted my code here that work well

Try changing your parameter

Your JSP Page

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"
type="text/javascript"></script>
```

```
<form id="form">
    Enter Your Name: <input type="text" id="userName" />
</form>
<br>
<br>

<strong>Ajax Response</strong>:
<div id="ajaxGetUserServletResponse"></div>
```

here is your ajax

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#form').submit(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url : 'GetUserServlet',
        data : {
            userName : $('#userName').val()
        },
        success : function(responseText) {
            $('#ajaxGetUserServletResponse').text(responseText);
        }
    });
});
```

});

your servlet file

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class GetUserServlet extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    String userName = request.getParameter("userName").trim();
    if(userName == null || "".equals(userName)){
        userName = "Guest";
    }

    String greetings = "Hello " + userName;

    response.setContentType("text/plain");
    response.getWriter().write(greetings);
}

}
```

Comment: you haven't send the request type from your ajax code then how you get into the servlet. Basically, i have a problem with data that return from the servlet and after that which will execute first either success or error.

Comment: No need because default request type is "GET"

Comment: in success do not assign parameter value to another variable direct use it like this success : function(data){  alert(data); }

Comment: I have just assigned this variable in success for another purpose but my concern is that I am unable to get data from doget() method in success by using response .getWriter().write(greetings)  so that I have used PrintWriter for this purpose as I have mentioned in my given answer

Comment: open page in google chrome  open developer mode by pressing ctrl+shift+i and goto network tab and check what your servlet file returns when you submit the form,as soon as you click/submit the form it display your servlet file name click on it and check the return data and also check that after click button your file is displayed or not into network tab

Comment: I know these process and u need to understand that in my  case response .getWriter().write() is not working so that I have assigned  PrintWriter out = response.getWriter() and use out.print() to return data in ajax as I have mentioned in my answer